# Prefix a string to json key in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to prefix 'd:' before the key of the json object , how can i do that

json data

```
"data": {
   "aa": "value",
   "ab": "value"
  }
```

Expected result :

```
"d:data": {
   "d:aa": "value",
   "d:ab": "value"
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update your question with your attempt(s). Take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```js
let foo = { "data": {
   "aa": "value",
   "ab": "value"
  }
}

function prefixObj(obj, prefix) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
        return [`${prefix}${key}`, typeof value === 'object' ? prefixObj(value, prefix) : value];
    }));
}

console.log(prefixObj(foo, 'd:'))
```